# What is the value of an XHR blocker?

Tags: web-browser, javascript

My question is not specific to uMatrix, but is framed from that PoV:

background info: uMatrix is a browser extension whose main interface offers a rectangular grid of permissions (allow/inherit/block), with domains and subdomains down the side and the following options across the top: Cookies, CSS, Images, Media (a/v & plugins), Scripts, XHR (including Fetch & WebSockets), Frames, Other.

Let's say I'm visiting the *example.com* website, which unfortunately calls a variety of URLs from *maliciousthirdparty.net*.

If my browser blocks scripts, media & frames from *maliciousthirdparty.net*, but allows XHR, does that permission by itself allow anything to happen at all? Can XHR be called from static HTML, CSS, cookies, or images?

Conversely, if my browser blocks XHR, but allows scripts or plugins, does that prevent *maliciousthirdparty.net* from achieving results that could not already be accomplished by another method instead (e.g. *createElement('script')*)?

In other words, what is an example where a separate XHR permission setting could be important?

Comment: You've overlooked the possibility of `example.com`'s JavaScript making an XHR request to `maliciousthirdparty.net`.

Comment: I was under the impression that cross-domain requests were forbidden. If that's incorrect, perhaps your comment should become an answer?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used CORS, and my knowledge has always been a little foggy in this area, but I believe it's up to `maliciousthirdparty.net` to allow the cross-origin request. Even if it were `example.com`'s decision it's possible they want to make requests to `innocentthirdparty.net`, but `innocentthirdparty.net` got hacked.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible for `example.com`'s JavaScript to make XHR requests to `maliciousthirdparty.net`. By default this is blocked due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), but `maliciousthirdparty.net` can send [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers to allow the requests.

If you block XHR requests to the domain while allowing scripts to be loaded from it, it may make it more difficult for a malicious script to exfiltrate data. This could be useful for example if you don't trust the CDN hosting a JavaScript library that `example.com` requires to function properly.